# How to change Dropdown lists value based on another Dropdown using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

I have three `<select>` dropdowns on my webpage: *Adult*, *Child* and *Infant* (think airline booking site).

In general, the *Adult* dropdown has options numbered 1-9, the *Child* dropdown has options numbered 0-8, and the *Infant* dropdown has options numbered 0-1. If a user selects *Adult* value *4*, the *Child* dropdown available numbers should change to reflect 0-5 and the *Infant* dropdown should change to reflect 0-4.

I'm trying to achieve this using javascript, but keep getting stuck. Happy to provide more information if necessary - just let me know what you need to see.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function MyApp(sender) {
    var ListBox1Id = '<%= ddl1.ClientID %>';
    var ListBox2Id = '<%= ddl2.ClientID %>';
    var ListBox3Id = '<%= ddl3.ClientID %>';

    var selectedIndex = document.getElementById(ListBox1Id).selectedIndex;
    var ii = document.getElementById(ListBox1Id).options[selectedIndex].value;
    var count = document.getElementById(ListBox1Id).length;

    if (ii != 0) {
        for (var k = 0; k <= count - ii; k++) {
            document.getElementById(ListBox2Id).value = k;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function I am calling on the *Adult* dropdown's `onchange` event, and I have written scripts for showing the *Child* dropdown's value based on the *Adult* dropdown's selection.

Comment: [AJAX Toolkit - CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I will post my code here now.,

Comment: What is the logic you are using to change the ddl values? means, selecting 4 in adult, why will child ddl consist 0-5, and infant consist 0-4??

Comment: @Avishek If we select 4 adults from Adult DDL, the Child DDL value starts from 0 to 5.(0,1,2,3,4,5) Please take a look at any AirTicket Booking site.

Comment: @Avishek was trying to ask the logic of why 0-5 and I too would like to know how we can decide 0-5(child) if 4(adult) is selected, I mean what if I select 5 or 6 or 7 in adult dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ListBox1Id = '<%= ddl1.ClientID %>';
var ListBox2Id = '<%= ddl2.ClientID %>';
var ListBox3Id = '<%= ddl3.ClientID %>';

var count = $("#"+ListBox1Id+"option:selected").text();
var listbox2 = document.getElementById(ListBox2Id);

listbox2.empty();
for(var i=0; i++; i <= count){
listbox2.append(
    $('<option></option>').val(i).html(i)
);
}
var listbox3 = document.getElementById(ListBox3Id);

listbox3.empty();
for(var j=0; j++; j < count){
listbox3.append(
    $('<option></option>').val(j).html(j)
);
}
```

Modify your code according to this, change count logics, if required, and it should be good to go.. Hope it helps :)

Comment: i have modified the line to get the count var. Please check.

Comment: @Thiri : Have you checked it yet?